# Minimising the number of Jenkins builds based on git hashes

Tags: git, jenkins

We use `git describe` to tag artifacts from Jenkins. I want to reduce the number of unnecessary builds, especially with non-fast-forward merge commits.

For example:

```
$ git log...
*   1c055de Merge branch 'other'  (branch master)
|\
| * d0de8ce commit2  (branch other)
|/
* 514ff3b commit1
```

In this case `other` has been built be Jenkins and created artifact `build-d0de8ce`.

`git diff master other` shows that the branches are equivalent. However `master` will now build the same artifact as `other` but as `build-1c055de`, which is a bit of a wasted effort.

My idea was, instead of the commit hash, to use the tree hash to tag the artifacts:

```
$ git rev-parse --short master^{tree}
6778206
$ git rev-parse --short other^{tree}
6778206
```

I just wanted to know if this is a good path to go down, or if there is a well-trodden path already.